# Laravel select 1line

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, select, line

There is a table in pma "ogsett", you need to select one line in it.
In the model, Ogsett indicated which table to work with.
In the controller (ServiceController) I indicated the following code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Service;
use App\Ogsett;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ServiceController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $og = Ogsett::wherePages('service');
        return view('price.main', compact('og'));
    }
```

On the page, I display it like this

```
@foreach($og as $seo_item)
{{ $seo_item->title }}
@endforeach
```

In it, I refer to this table, and select the field with the value title - service.
But my data is not displayed on the page.

The base itself looks like this

```
=======================================================
|ID|PAGES| TITLE|DESCRIPTION|URL|IMAGES|LOCAL|SITE_NAME|
=======================================================
| 1|service|TitlePage|DescPage Service|service|images.jpg|en|localhost|
| 2|contact|ContactPage|DescPage Contact|conatact|images.jpg|en|localhost|
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Use `$og = Ogsett::wherePages('service')->firstOrFail();`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate over all the titles you will have to do this

```
 $og = Ogsett::wherePages('service')->get();
```

and then in your blade

```
@foreach($og as $seo_item)
{{ $seo_item->title }}
@endforeach
```

Alternatively you could also use if you only want the title and do not require the other db cols

```
$og = Ogsett::wherePages('service')->pluck('title');
```

and then on the blade you can

```
 @foreach($og as $seo_item)
{{ $seo_item }}
@endforeach
```